# h:outputLink prefixes server name to an external url linked to

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, hyperlink, external

Here's the line giving the problem:

```
<h:outputLink value="http://myfavirates.org/comlogs/104247.pdf">See log file </h:outputLink>
```

When it's rendered, jsf always prefixes the url with the site name. For example,

```
http://localhost:8282/commoninfo/%20%20http://myfavirates.org/comlogs/104247.pdf
```

How could I take it out?

Comment: no log file to look at? no source code? We need more information

Comment: I put the line there, but it was stripped out:  <h:outputLink value="http ://myfavirates.org/comlogs/104247.pdf">See log</h:outputLink>   I tested on my local tomcat.

Comment: I fixed the epic formatting fail. In future, pay more attention and love to preview area below the message editor. As to the concrete problem, which JSF impl/version are you using? Tried the latest? Nonetheless, why not just using `<a>` instead of a whole `<h:outputLink>`? This is JSF 2.x, not JSF 1.0.

Comment: <a> is not working the way I want.  Here's what I did: <h:outputLink value="#{mf.localLogUrl}" rendered="#{mf.showLocalLog}">See local log</h:outputLink>  mf.localLogUrl="http://locahost:8282/log101.xhtml"
<h:outputLink value="#{mf.localExternalUrl}" rendered="#{mf.showLocalLog}">See log</h:outputLink> mf.localExternalUrl="http://myfavirate.org/comlogs/104247.pdf". The first works just fine, but if I link to a pdf file, the problem occurs.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @BalusC  Thanks for your tip. I wrapped <a> in a jsf label and solved the problem.  This is the first time I raised a question, and got your answer. I really appreciate it.Regards, lee1

Comment: Which JSF impl/version are you using? Tried the latest?